# How do I safely store customer's username?

Tags: php, cookies

On my website, upon signing in, my customer's username get's stored in a cookie which expires in 15 days, and whenever he comes back to my site, I added a php code that checks 1) do they have the cookie anymore 2) is the username from there valid. I also did the same thing with hashed password but I was told it is dangerous and that I should remove that with password. Now, anybody can just change the value of the cookie to another username. What is the safe way to solve this? What should I add / remove? Is storing hashed password dangerous after all? Any help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are fully familiar with the concept of "Session". Usually, storing sensitive info in cookies is very dangerous. Usually it's best to store a session ID and and the session info in a database (Redis for example is a key-value database which is usually a good choice for session caching). On each request, a middleware code intercepts HTTP requests, checks the cookie for session ID and checks the DB if the session is valid. Not sure what framework you are working on, but most popular for PHP are [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session) and [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html). As for passwords, make sure to use **bcrypt** algorithm, it's made to be relatively slow, so bruteforcing passwords is not a valid option for an attacker.

Comment: I understand, except one thing. When a customer signs in and leaves the browser and later comes again, I want him to stay logged in, but I wouldn't have the cookie to identify his username, and as far as I know, session is destroyed upon closing the browser. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Persistence of session depends on how you configure it, if you do not set an expiration date for cookies, they will be destroyed after closing the browser. So, set the expiration date. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Session_cookies)